# Find the speed of the tip of a shadow reflecting off a man walking away from a street light?

Tags: calculus

A street light is at the top of a 11.000 ft. tall pole. A man 5.500 ft tall walks away from the pole with a speed of 3.500 feet/sec along a straight path. How fast is the tip of his shadow moving when he is 50.000 feet from the pole?

So, Dx/Dt=3.5, not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Let $y(x)$ be the position of the tip of the shadow given the man's position $x$ (this requires some geometry work). Calculate $dy/dx$. Use chain rule to get $dy/dt$.

Answer (score 3):

You really need a picture here:

[image]

\begin{align}
L:&\text{ height of Lamp} \\
H:&\text{ height of man} \\
x:&\text{ distance from lamp to man}\\
s:&\text{ distance from lamp to tip of shadow}
\end{align}

It's helpful to introduce the part $s - x$ because you should recognize that you have similar triangles: $1$) the small one with $s - x$ and $H$ and $2$) the large one with $s$ and $L$.  Those ratios must be equal:

$$
\frac{L}{s} = \frac{H}{s - x} \text{ or } \frac{s}{L} = \frac{s - x}{H} \\
\frac{1}{L}s - \frac{1}{H}s = -\frac{1}{H}x \\
s = -\frac{HL}{(H - L)H}x = \frac{L}{L - H}x \\
\frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{L}{L - H}\frac{dx}{dt}
$$

Note that the speed of the shadow depends only on $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and not the distance from the lamp.  Also note that the shadow tip always moves away from the person since $L > L - H$ which makes the coefficient in front of $\frac{dx}{dt}$ strictly greater than $1$.

**Or you could draw *this* picture:**

[image]

Now the two similar triangles are the top, small one and, again, the large (full) one, giving:

$$
\frac{x}{L - H} = \frac{s}{L} \rightarrow s = \frac{L}{L - H}x
$$

...of course we get the same thing as before!

Answer (score 1):

This is something that you should draw to understand the details.  The 11-ft tall pole, the distance from the bottom of the pole to the tip of the man's shadow, and the distance from the top of the pole to the tip of the man's shadow form a large triangle.  Additionally, the man's height, the top of the man's head to the tip of his shadow, and the distance from the feet of the man to the tip of the shadow form a smaller triangle.  We can use this information to find the desired answer.  Indeed, since these triangles described are similar, there is proportionality at play here - we can glean the following equation from examination of the situation, where $h$ is the height of the man's shadow and $x$ is the distance from the bottom of the pole to the man's feet at any given time (thus, $x+h$ is the distance from the bottom of the pole to the tip of the man's shadow - this is the base of the larger triangle), $$\frac{11}{x+h}=\frac{5.5}{h}.$$
Now, rearrange this equation to find a linear relationship between $h$ and $x$: $\,\,\,h=x$. Taking the derivative of both sides of this with respect to $t$, where $t$ is the time in seconds, to get $$\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}=3.5$$
It is important to recognize that the speed of the tip of the shadow does not depend upon the distance of the man from the pole, as we can see from the form of $dh/dt$.  In other words, the speed of the tip of the shadow is constant at the rate at which the man walks away from the pole, with these dimensions, regardless of how far away he is from the pole.

Comment: If the distance from the man doesn't matter, why does x= the distance from the bottom of the pole to the man's feet?

Comment: I shouldn't say irrelevant, that was the wrong word.  Often when we are determining the answers to these types of questions, it is necessary to find the desired quantity as function of other variables.  Then, it is sometimes the case that the desired quantity is actually independent of those variables. @Natalie

Comment: Look at the last equation - does the function for $dh/dt$ depend upon $x$? It does not depend upon $x$, but directly upon its derivative, which is constant according to the problem (if it was not constant, and depended on something else, then I would have to amend my statement).

Comment: Thank you for trying, I'm just not picking up on it for some reason. I would up-vote you but I don't have enough reputation points yet.

Comment: @Natalie: What is confusing you exactly? Do you understand the equation that I developed from the geometry of the situation? What step is giving you problems, this would help me to clear it up?

Comment: I think I'm just too tired to do math at the moment. all the d()/d() are getting mixed up.

Comment: Maybe writing out the steps of what I explain will make it clear to you...let me know if I can help when you are less tired!

Comment: The answer here gives the speed of length of the shadow, not the tip. Check the answer of @jared.

Answer (score 0):

you have to draw 2 triangles, one from the man to the end of the shadow and a big triangle including the small as part of it and the top of the street light, and then you can resolve that.